# What is the difference between `wine` and `wine64`?

Tags: wine

I would like to understand what is the difference between `wine` and `wine64`.
Tried googling but cannot find a normal explanation.

The reason I am asking is because I have **2 exe files**, **32-bit** and **64-bit** (same program, just 2 variants for different archituctures) and both of them work fine both using `wine` and `wine64`.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit). What is the "correct" way to run it?

Comment: The difference: https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Is_there_a_64_bit_Wine.3F

Answer (score 8):

According to [winehq.org](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Is_there_a_64_bit_Wine.3F)

> - 32 bit Wine runs on both 32-bit and 64-bit Linux/Unix installations. 16-bit and 32-bit Windows applications will run on it.
> - 64-bit Wine runs only on 64 bit installations, and so far has only been extensively tested on Linux. It requires the installation of 32 bit libraries in order to run 32 bit Windows applications. Both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows applications (should) work with it;" however, there are still many [bugs](https://bugs.winehq.org/buglist.cgi?keywords=win64&resolution=---).

Use the one that works for you.If your applications work with either consider yourself lucky and use either one. There is no right or wrong, just what works for you.

Sources:

- https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Is_there_a_64_bit_Wine.3F
- https://bugs.winehq.org/buglist.cgi?keywords=win64&resolution=---

Comment: Is there any benefit to installing both `wine` and `wine64`?

Comment: @Flimm at the risk of repeating myself, Use the one that works for you.If your applications work with either consider yourself lucky and use either one. There is no right or wrong, just what works for you.